# jQuery collision between two divs not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-collision

I am using the Jquery collision plugin from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jquerycollision/wiki/Home/) and tried a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/chandrashekarthota/uvw4kn71/26/). I am trying to check the collision result when a user moves one object over the other.  It is not working as expected and it throws an error stating collision is not defined.

Jquery Code

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

  //Move arrow keys
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    $("#object1").animate({
      left: "-=5"
    }, 0);
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    $("#object1").animate({
      top: "-=5"
    }, 0);
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    $("#object1").animate({
      left: "+=5"
    }, 0);
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    $("#object1").animate({
      top: "+=5"
    }, 0);
  }


  var colliders_selector = "#object1";
  var obstacles_selector = "#object2";
  var hits = $(colliders_selector).collision(obstacles_selector);
  alert(hits);
});
```

HTML code

```
<div id='object1'>

</div>

<div id='object2'>

</div>
```

Comment: You've loaded `jquery.overlaps.js` which is not the same as `jquery-collision`. `jquery-overlaps` has the same functionality but it is used differently (eg: `$(colliders_selector). overlaps(obstacles_selector)`)

Comment: @Titus yes correct include 'jquery-collision.min.js' file its not came error

Comment: Go to this url download and include https://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/files/